# Git rebase not showing merge commit

Tags: git, github

I pulled code from upstream and merged it with my code.

In upstream currently, there are only my previous commits, and PR merge commits.

When I pulled the code, it showed this message `Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.`

Then I pushed it to my forked copy on github.

This created a new commit with the following message:

`Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/Girl-Code-It/Girl-Code-It… …`

I wanted to squash my previous commit.

Now when I do `git log`

The latest commit is Merged message one

But when I type `git rebase -i HEAD~2`, then it shows me the 2nd last commit and 3rd last, in other words acts like Merge commit never happened.

I have 2 questions

1. What is the issue? What I did wrong and should avoid later on.
2. How to fix it.

Comment: Consider reading the docs. That is why they exist. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase "By default, a rebase will simply drop merge commits from the todo list..." You might also ask yourself _why_ you think you need to include the merge commit in the list; what useful thing could you do if it were there? Is there really anything here that you need to "fix"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebase usually skips all the merge commits, which is usually what you want since rebase puts all your commits into a single line.

If you want it to try to keep the merges, and the structure, experiment with `git rebase -p` or `git rebase -r`.